# HTML form to ask email address then use javascript to spit it back out into html page as a link

Tags: javascript, html

I am not sure where my code is going wrong or what its missing 
2 things I need to ask my visitors is what town they are from and what their email address is
Once they give me those two things I am supposed to spit back their town + the words is a great town and then their email address as a link.
So far only the first part of my objectives is working...cant quite get the email part figured out

So far my function looks like this:

```
function promptTown() {
    var town = document.getElementById("city").value;
    document.getElementById("niceTown").innerHTML = town +" is a great town!";
    var emailAddress = document.getElementById("email").value;
    document.getElementById("emailFormat").write.href = ("mailto:"  +emailAddress);
}`
```

and HTML is

```
<div class="town"> City/Town: <input type="text" id="city"><br>
   Email Address: <input type="email" id="email"> 
   <button onclick="promptTown()">Submit</button><br>
   <p id="niceTown" class="townTalk"></p> 
   <p id="emailFormat" class="emailUnderline"></p> 
</div>
```

Comment: When is this `promptTown` function called? Also how does the emailFormat element looks like in html

Comment: The promptTown function is called as onclick button after the input type

Comment: <div class="town">
        City/Town: <input type="text" id="city"><br>
        Email Address: <input type="email" id="email">
        <button onclick="promptTown()">Submit</button><br>
        <p id="niceTown" class="townTalk"></p>
        <p id="emailFormat" class="emailUnderline"></p>
    </div>

Comment: Change `<p id="emailFormat" class="emailUnderline"></p>` to `<a id="emailFormat" class="emailUnderline">Email</a>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use `setAttribute(name, value)` method of the element (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

Something like this should work:

```js
document.getElementById("emailFormat").setAttribute("href", "mailto:"  + emailAddress);
```

PS: You might want to use string extrapolation for better clarity if you target modern web browsers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
document.getElementById("emailFormat").setAttribute("href", `mailto:${emailAddress}`);
```

Comment: OP is using <p> element for email. href won't work on it :)

Comment: Beautiful - i just had to add the : to mailto and then i could use" document.getElementById("emailFormat").innerHTML = emailAddress;" and it opened up my email client - Thanks much to all